# Laravel 5.6 Jquery Ajax 500 internal server error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

Please am getting 500 internal server error on a student portal am creating. Anytime I tried to post a program using post request. However, the same code works when I tried posting the academic year. I am working in laravel 5.6. Please before my question gets voted down, I have read a lot of solutions here but non seemed to work for me.

This is the error:

> "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'program' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into programs () values ())" trace : [{file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php",…},…]

program.blade.php

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" name="program" id="program" class="form-control" placeholder="Program">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" name="description" id="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn-save-program" type="button">Save</button>
</div>
```

select form

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <label for="program">Programs</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <select name="program_id" id="program_id" class="form-control">
    </select>
    <div id="add-more-program" class="btn input-group-addon">
      <span class="icon_plus"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Program.php (model)

```
protected $table = 'programs';
protected $fillable = [
    'program', 'description'
];
protected $primaryKey = 'program_id';
public $timestamps = false;
```

The controller

```
public function InsertProgram(Request $request) {
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response(Program::create($request->all()));
    }
}
```

The js code

```
    $('#btn-save-program').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var program = $('#program').val();
  var description = $('#description').val();
  $.post("{{ route('InsertProgram') }}", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
})
```

And finally the Web Route

```
Route::post('courses/manage/create-program', 'CourseController@InsertProgram')->name('InsertProgram');
```

Comment: A 500 error indicates a problem on your server. Firstly check the response in the network tab of the console to see what the exact response is. Then check your server logs for a clue as to exactly what's causing the problem.

Comment: This is the response from my network
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'program' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `programs` () values ())"
trace
:
[{file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php",…},…]

I've already created the project with laravel but now am trying to make it real time that's why am using ajax and am getting that error anytime I tried making the post request

Comment: I edited that in to your question for you. Hopefully someone with more knowledge of Laravel will be able to help you

Comment: The error says that you are creating a `Program` without any values, so make sure you are actually sending and receiving the values for the `Program` in the `$request`. You can check this by looking at the request rather than the response in the network tab.

Comment: How will I do that? because there is no indication in the network tab

Comment: This is mostly because the `program` column on your MySQL table doesn't have any default value, and your insert doesn't provide a `program` value (or at least doesn't reach the insert statement).

Could you try dump your `$request->all()` value to see what's inside? Also, please provide JS code (the one handling the ajax POST request).

Comment: I've edited the question with the js code
After dumping the request->all() I get this in the console 
[]length: 0__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score 0):

I have finally resolved it after working around it
The problem is with my ajax post request
I am trying to send a null value of program to MYSQL table which doesn't have a default value. So I used this jquery instead

```
$('#btn-save-program').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var program = $('#new-program').val();
  var description = $('#new-description').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ route('InsertProgram') }}",
    data: { program: program, description: description },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  })
})
```

I changed the id of both program and description in program.blade.php file to #new-program and #new-description to prevent conflict.

Hence I am able to provide the data values for "program" and "description".
The model, controller and web routes works just fine